# Item click of recyclerview opens another recyclerview

Tags: java, php, android, api

I have a category list which contains item from the API displayed using a `RecyclerView`. On click of a category I want to display the data list respective to that category in another `RecyclerView`. I am implementing the above in fragments. I want to know how to manage dynamic data.

Eg:

Category 1

Category 2

Category 3

Category 4

Category 5

onclick Category 2 >>

RecyclerView item 1

RecyclerView item 2

RecyclerView item 3

RecyclerView item 4

onclick RecyclerView item 2

open another fragment containing detailed description respective to `RecyclerView item 2`

**How can i achieve this???**

Comment: Initial you need to create custom call backs for recyclerview adapter. In this custom click you need to get the id of position and then pass the id to api to get detail info of the item

Comment: You want show Categories and respective data on same recyclerview  or different recyclerview?   If you want to show on Single RecyclerView then use `ExpandableListView` instead of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir As there are a lot of items i am going to open them in another frag

Comment: You can create callbacks and replace fragment accordingly.